# AWS Console timeout when logged in using `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` role in member account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a login for the AWS organization management account `foo` in my organization "Example FooBar Company". When I log in to the management account, my session stays active all day. Maybe it's 12 hours—I don't know. Whatever it is, it's reasonable and adequate.

My organization has a member account `bar`. I didn't bother creating a login user in `bar`. Instead, I log in to `foo` and [switch to the `bar` account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html) using the `OrganizationAccountAccessRole`. (See [*AWS Cross Account Access*](https://crishantha.medium.com/aws-cross-account-access-70c5b2fac543) for an explanation.)

I would like to work all day in the `bar` account. Unfortunately *every hour or so* AWS decides signs me out with the message:

> You were signed out of your account. Please press ‘Reload’ to sign in to the AWS Management Console again.

As this happens again and again all day, it begins to get extremely irritating, especially when I have half a dozen tabs open across the screen in the middle of tracking down some bug. Moreover when the tabs reload they often have their settings (e.g. filters) reset, or they have to reload the logs I was looking at, so I have to start over. In my opinion it's somewhat (perhaps not totally, but somewhat) pointless, because the "sign in again" procedure is simply reloading the page, which anyone could do if I walked away from a laptop in a coffee shop and got lost. Logging me out without asking for new credentials brings more usability pain than security gain. If my session for `foo` is valid for 12 hours, I want my session for `bar` to be valid for 12 hours.

I imagine I could manually create a distinct, direct login user for `bar` instead of using the `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` role, but then I would have the pain of keeping track of user logins for all the accounts in the organization (not to mention going through the ordeal of creating a new root user in each organization just to be able to create users in those organizations).

Is there any way to extend the AWS console session timeout to something reasonable when logged in to an organization's member account via the `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` role from a user in the management account?

Comment: Be aware of [Set Session Duration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/howtosessionduration.html). Not 100% sure it's appropriate in your case, but hopefully.

Comment: "...if I walked away from a laptop in a coffee shop and got lost"   Don't do this!

Comment: When you say "have a login" it looks like you mean "IAM user", right? If so, I think you should modify your question because the timeout rules are different if you are coming in as a federated user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, one hour is the default.

> By default, when you switch roles, your AWS Management Console session lasts for 1 hour.

[Switching Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-console.html#id_roles_iam_user-switch-role-console-things-to-know)

However:

> IAM users who switch roles in the console are granted the role maximum session duration, or the remaining time in the user's session, whichever is less.

In your case, you need to modify the OrganizationAccountAccessRole in the `bar` account to have a MaximumSessionDuration up to 12 hours.

[image: Here's mine as an example]

Comment: Zaq, I cannot give this answer enough love. It works exactly as expected!! You have just removed a recurring irritation from my days. This is wonderful. I appreciate your taking the time to answer. Thank you.

Comment: Garret, glad it helped.  I ran into this a couple of years ago using Cloudwatch dashboards on a screen in the DevOps office.  Using a special read-only role and cycling through multiple tabs for individual accounts, this was really annoying.

Comment: The corollary to this is that if you did NOT authenticate as an IAM user (e.g. a federated role) then it appears you are stuck with the 1 hour "default". I have an AWS support ticket open now to confirm that "by default" really means "you can't change it"(!)

Comment: @NR, This page says you can, with SAML 2.0 Federation.  "You can also specify the maximum time (up to 12 hours) that users can access the console before having to refresh their credentials."  
[Enabling SAML 2.0 federated users to access the AWS Management Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_enable-console-saml.html)

Comment: @Zaq - yep you can. The issue is that if you then switch to another role you are stuck with the 1-hour timeout. Even if the target role sets it to something higher! AWS support just confirmed this - they said they will be updating their documentation regarding the "by default" wordage they have in the docs.

Comment: That's annoying!